# Open Youtube and Tumblr link in app rather than browser - Unity

Tags: youtube, tumblr, unity-game-engine, social-media

I've managed to make it so when clicking specific buttons it loads up Facebook, Twitter and Instagram using `fb://------`, `twitter://----` and `instagram://-----`, but I can't seem to find one for YouTube or Tumblr. Is there any way to do this?

Edit: This is my current code. (Sorry for the slow reply)

```
// Set buttontype in editor depending on which button it is
// 0 = facebook, 1 = instagram, 2 = tumblr, 3 = twitter, 4 = youtube
public int buttonType;

// Web urls - use this for computers or if the user doesn't have the app installed on phones
private string[] webUrls = { 
    "https://www.facebook.com/-------",
    "https://www.instagram.com/--------",
    "http://--------.tumblr.com/",
    "https://twitter.com/----------",
    "https://youtube.com/user/--------"
};

// Use this for android - loads the app - if don't have the app, default to weburls
private string[] appUrls = {
    "fb://page/--------",
    "instagram://user?username=---------",
    "http://-------.tumblr.com/",
    "twitter://user?user_id=-------",
    "https://youtube.com/user/--------"
}; 

void OnMouseDown()
{
    // Checks which device it's running on - STANDALONE is windows/mac/linux
    #if UNITY_STANDALONE
        Application.OpenURL (webUrls[buttonType]);
    #endif

    #if UNITY_ANDROID
        Application.OpenURL (appUrls[buttonType]);

        // Do a check to see if they have the app installed
        StartCoroutine(CheckApp());
        launchedApp = false;
    #endif

}

// If switched app, set to true so it won't launch the browser
void OnApplicationPause()
{
    launchedApp = true;
}

IEnumerator CheckApp()
{
    // Wait for a time
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (waitTime);

    // If app hasn't launched, default to opening in browser
    if(!launchedApp)
    {
        Application.OpenURL (webUrls[buttonType]);
    }
}
```

I simply wait a bit, if the app hasn't launched, I open it in the browser on Android.

Also, the normal YouTube link *sometimes* asks if you want to open it in the app, not all the time which is quite annoying.

**Edit:** After searching for a hell of a long time, I finally found it.

```
tumblr://x-callback-url/blog?blogName=BLOGNAME
```

The full list of social media that I'll be using are:

```
fb://page/PAGEIDNUMBER
instagram://user?username=USERNAME
tumblr://x-callback-url/blog?blogName=BLOGNAME
twitter://user?user_id=USERID
https://youtube.com/user/USERNAME
```

Replace the caps with your specific pages. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Do you have any code to share?

Comment: hi @dan if possible just edit in a couple of lines of code showing how you use the items you have working.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply, code is now added :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** After searching for a hell of a long time, I finally found it.

```
tumblr://x-callback-url/blog?blogName=BLOGNAME
```

The full list of social media that I'll be using are:

```
fb://page/PAGEIDNUMBER
instagram://user?username=USERNAME
tumblr://x-callback-url/blog?blogName=BLOGNAME
twitter://user?user_id=USERID
https://youtube.com/user/USERNAME
```

Replace the caps with your specific pages. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Using `youtu.be/LINK` for the youtube allows you to open users, channels and video link.

Hope it helps somebody :)