# Open another app and pass in url

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

I'm trying on unity to open the Google+ app when I click on a button.
I run the app on my android device but it's not working 
this is the code I used

```
Application.OpenURL ("gplus://plus.google.com/+JewelMash");
```

---

this code works but it prompts you to choose to open it with a browser or google + app

```
Application.OpenURL ("https://plus.google.com/+JewelMash");
```

Comment: but it is not working.....What is not working? What do you expect to happen and what's happening at this moment?

Comment: thank you for your reply I'm trying to do something like this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35544165/open-youtube-and-tumblr-link-in-app-rather-than-browser-unity  this line of code code Application.OpenURL ("plus.google.com/+JewelMash"); prompt you to choose between g+ app or the browsers you have on your mobile,if you choose the browser the google plus page opens. but if you choose google plus app it shows this error [link]https://postimg.org/image/50lufh0zn/  . but Application.OpenURL ("gplus://plus.google.com/+JewelMash"); doesn't open the google + app

Comment: Ok, Check my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The  Application.OpenURL function cannot do this. I've done this before and willing to share. You can make a Java plugin to do this or you can use [`AndroidJavaClass`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaClass.html) and C# to do it. I did mine in C# since this is a simple plugin.

To Open any App:

```
public bool openUrl(string packageName)
{
    #if UNITY_ANDROID
    AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    AndroidJavaObject unityActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    AndroidJavaObject pManager = unityActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getPackageManager");

    AndroidJavaObject intent = null;
    try
    {
        intent = pManager.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getLaunchIntentForPackage", packageName);
        unityActivity.Call("startActivity", intent);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Failed to Opeen App: " + e.Message);
        //Open with Browser
        string link = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageName + "&hl=en";

        Application.OpenURL(link);
        return false;
    }
    #endif
    return false;
}
```

**Usage**:

```
bool success = openUrl("com.google.android.apps.plus");
```

To Open another App then pass in Url:

```
public bool openUrl(string packageName, string url)
{
    #if UNITY_ANDROID
    AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    AndroidJavaObject unityActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    AndroidJavaObject pManager = unityActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getPackageManager");

    //For accessing static strings(ACTION_VIEW) from android.content.Intent
    AndroidJavaClass intentStaticClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Intent");
    string actionView = intentStaticClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_VIEW");

    //Create Uri
    AndroidJavaClass uriClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");
    AndroidJavaObject uriObject = uriClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("parse", url);

    //Psss ACTION_VIEW and Uri.parse to the intent
    AndroidJavaObject intent = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent", actionView, uriObject);

    try
    {
        if (pManager.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getPackageInfo", packageName, 0) != null)
        {
            intent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setPackage", packageName);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Failed to Open App 1: " + e.Message);
        return false;
    }

    try
    {
        unityActivity.Call("startActivity", intent);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Failed to Open App 2: " + e.Message);
        //Open with Browser
        string link = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageName + "&hl=en";

        Application.OpenURL(link);
        return false;
    }
    #endif
    return false;
}
```

**Usage**:

```
 bool success = openUrl("com.google.android.apps.plus", "https://plus.google.com/+JewelMash");
```

You are looking for the second code. If you want to find the package name of another app use the image below:

[image]

This solution is for Android. You will need Object-C plugin to do this in iOS. I suggest you ask a new question about how to do this in iOS.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
thank you for your answer

open url works for other apps like twitter facebook & instagram (it opens the defalt application) but for google+ it doesn't open the app maybe this url is not correct

Application.OpenURL ("gplus://plus.google.com/+JewelMash");