# Opening an android studio application(apk) from a Unity android application with a button

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I want to merge my applications so that when I navigate through the unity android application User Interface and click a button, my built android studio application would pop up. How do I do so?

Comment: A duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731238/open-another-app-and-pass-in-url/41745808#41745808)

Answer (score -1):

Try this written by [kingandroid at unity forums](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/android-ios-launch-from-within-a-unity-app-another-unity-app.222709/#post-1486300)

```
        bool fail = false;
        string bundleId = com.google.appname; // your target bundle id
        AndroidJavaClass up = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        AndroidJavaObject ca = up.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        AndroidJavaObject packageManager = ca.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getPackageManager");

        AndroidJavaObject launchIntent = null;
        try
        {
            launchIntent = packageManager.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getLaunchIntentForPackage",bundleId);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            fail = true;
        }

        if (fail)
        { //open app in store
            Application.OpenURL("https://google.com");
        }
        else //open the app
            ca.Call("startActivity",launchIntent);

        up.Dispose();
        ca.Dispose();
        packageManager.Dispose();
        launchIntent.Dispose();
```

This code is for opening a Unity app from within a Unity app. I'm not an expert on Android (or android studio) so I don't know for sure if it will work with those apps.

Hope it helps!