# Open another app (chrome) and pass a url in unity c# in android

Tags: c#, android, google-chrome, unity-game-engine

How can I access and open google chrome app from a unity app that's running in android? I saw a similar solution in this post: [Open another app and pass in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731238/open-another-app-and-pass-in-url) but it's doing google plus. Does somebody have any clue to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731238/open-another-app-and-pass-in-url) reference you posted

You can use string `com.android.chrome` to open chrome app

```
bool success = openUrl("com.android.chrome", "https://YOUR_LINK");
```

Comment: I tried it but for a weird reason, it doesn't seem to work, maybe it's because of this line "com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer" because I'm using unity2d

Comment: It seems that it doesn't get through the first line of the function openUrl, since I put some msg texts to display at each part of the function. It doesn't work

Comment: No, Don’t put any text other than url in the second parameter